# JQuery remove div not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

I'm not really a javascript/jquery coder, I have a very simple code to remove a div that's not working in IE

I'm using this in a Joomla page, so I call it like this:

```
$document->addScript("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js");//adiciona jquery
```

And than, in the body document:

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#yourDiv").remove();
    }, 50000);
</script>
```

FireFox and Chrome are (as always) ok. Can someone point out my mistake please? Thanks a lot :)

EDITED ************************

I've tryied also with this code no jquery, but always not working in IE (9)

```
<script>
setTimeout('yourFunction();', 5000);
function yourFunction(){
var div = document.getElementById("yourDiv");
div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Does it work in IE with a lower value in the timeout, say `2000`?

Comment: seems like the timeout's too high

Comment: Do you have a sample page you can point to? Nothing there looks like it shouldn't work.

Comment: Also try setting a type for your `<script>` tag...

Comment: Have you verified that IE is loading the jQuery script?

Comment: @Joseph I agree. IE is pretty dumb at the best of times. Asking it to count to 50,000 is just cruel.

Comment: i skimmed this link and it looked relevant: http://alexle.net/archives/169, even it it's not: what version of IE?

Comment: Are you talking about seconds people ? 50000 I thought this should set up cound to 50 seconds?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#yourDiv").remove();
    }, 50000);
});
</script>
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/EGJGU/), it's working in ie too.

Comment: If the timeout was lower this may make a difference, but the page and all it's scripts should have loaded within 50 seconds.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is also not working in IE, so for my pain should it be more than the code problem ? :(

Comment: Are you sure jquery is loaded ?

Comment: Check source inside head tag if there is a script tag containing link to jquery src=".../jquery-1.7.1.min.js".

Comment: Yes, there's the script tag <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @SheikhHeera no, it's not working yet, I found that IE says I got a syntax erro in the line which contains only </script> and I don't have idea what could it be due to, any suggestions?

Comment: Try to add inside your head <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script> and remove/disable $document->addScript temporarily. Src should be http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js

Comment: Thanks a lot Sheikh Heera! that's solved the problem, so I really think it's a Joomla matter as well. :)

Comment: Welcome and glad that my 5 votes for this answer from others is now valuable to me and I could help you.

Comment: I don't know how this work's but im sure with me is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this addScript doesn't work. Check if jQuery is loaded:

```
alert(typeof($));
```

This alert message would return **function** or **undefined**.

Comment: Hi Paulo Rodrigues, I've to add this line in my script, but it's just being ignored and I don't get any alert..

Comment: I mean, of course if I load the page with IE I don't get any alert, if I load it with FF I get alert 'function'

Comment: Add this code on first line of javascript, not inner `ready` function of jQuery.

Comment: Yes, it is in first line of javascript <script>
alert(typeof($));  :(

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I did it and I got a SCRIPT1012 syntax error on line 451 , which is: </script>  :( I also typed my start script tag <script type="text/javascript"> but nothing changes. Do you have any idea of what's wrong?..

Answer (score 1):

I tested this in internet explorer and firefox, works in both.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var p = {
        onload: function() {
            setTimeout(
                function() {
                    var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
                    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
                },
                3000
            );
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
    <body onload="p.onload()">
    <div id="myDiv" style="height: 50px; width: 50px ;background-color: grey;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you think this would work, when the jQuery approach didn't?

Comment: I really don't know where to put this, I have trying plain javascript removeChild but I couldn't make it work in none browsers. Would you please rewrite with the missing parts to make it work? Thanks a lot!

Comment: JQeury is a library, if some of it's code doesn't work in one browser, it's a good idea to try it with pure javascript. It's possible it still doesn't work, then it's something else. I guess it's probably cause jquery isn't loaded yet when using IE. Using document.ready() would solve that

Comment: @Tom After read your comment, I went to google about using document.ready() and I found that it should be in the end of the page to get to work in IE. I couldn't find anything else about, the fact is my script is already in the end of the page. So, what do you mean exactly when you say using document.ready()? Thank you!

Comment: @Tom I edited my question and tryied a plain JS code with your suggestion, but always not working in IE (?) ;(

Comment: @Tom - Thanks a lot, I tryied this one too, but the matter is I'm working with Joomla and it returns me a series of different strange errors in FF and IE, so I can't use it like I could in a simple plain page. :(

Comment: In the end now it's working after I combined your code and the other's advices, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: glad to be able to help, too bad someone felt they had to vote down my efforts

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and eventually realized I was using .append to a div and mistakenly also adding my own closing div.

IE is very picky about having elements nested properly.