# JavaScript remove() doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have the following code in JavaScript:

```
all_el_ul = document.getElementsByClassName('element_list')[0];
div_list = all_el_ul.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (i = 0; i < div_list.length; i += 1) {         
  div_list[i].remove();             
}
```

I know that this is the problem because I used `alert('test');` to see where the code stops working.
Everything is working in FF, Chrome, Opera and others but not in IE.

Could you please tell what is wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery remove div not working in Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443470/jquery-remove-div-not-working-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.remove): *"Because this technology's specification has not stabilized, check the compatibility table for the proper prefixes to use in various browsers. Also note that the syntax and behavior of an experimental technology is subject to change in future versions of browsers as the spec changes."*

Comment: @Bartdude: No, that's not the problem here.

Comment: @AlexPac Could you please mark one of the anwser as resolved ?

Answer (score 93):

> IE doesn't support `remove()` native Javascript function but does
>   support `removeChild()`.

## Browser compatibility for remove()

[image: Desktop browser compatipility for remove() function]

[image: Mobile browser compatipility for remove() function]

## Solution n°1

**Use `remove()`** in pure Javascript you can **declare it yourself** with this following code :

```
// Create Element.remove() function if not exist
if (!('remove' in Element.prototype)) {
    Element.prototype.remove = function() {
        if (this.parentNode) {
            this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
        }
    };
}
// Call remove() according to your need
child.remove();
```

As you can see the function get the parent node of element and then remove this element from his parent with `removeChild()` native function.

## Solution n°2

**Use `removeChild()`** in pure JavaScript on all browser including IE just call it insteed of `remove()`.

```
element.removeChild(child);
```

[More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)  on Mozilla Developer Network.

## Solution n°3

**Use jQuery** through [code.jquery.com CDN](https://code.jquery.com) by using this following code :

```
<!-- Include jQuery -->
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Use remove() -->
<script>
child.remove();
</script>
```

The function is included in the jQuery library so you can call it after inclusion.

*Happy coding ! :-)*

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Solution n°1 is very elegant and works like a charm. +1

Comment: Somehow it throws an error with jquery as well. I think you have to use `$(child).remove();` instead of `child.remove();` to make it work?

Comment: I used solution n°1 because it requires 0 extra lines of code.

Answer (score 25):

The native [`childNode.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) is a new experimental method that is not is supported in Internet Explorer, only in Edge

Compatibility table from [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)

[image]
[image]

You could use the more widely supported [`Node.removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) instead

```
var all_el_ul = document.getElementsByClassName('element_list')[0];
var div_list  = all_el_ul.getElementsByTagName("div");

for (i = 0; i < div_list.length; i += 1) {         
   div_list[i].parentNode.removeChild(div_list[i]);             
}
```

or use the [polyfill from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove#Polyfill) to add support for all browsers

```
(function (arr) {
  arr.forEach(function (item) {
    if (item.hasOwnProperty('remove')) {
      return;
    }
    Object.defineProperty(item, 'remove', {
      configurable: true,
      enumerable: true,
      writable: true,
      value: function remove() {
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
      }
    });
  });
})([Element.prototype, CharacterData.prototype, DocumentType.prototype]);
```

There is also a [`remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) method in jQuery, that *does* work cross-browser, but that would require adding the jQuery library.

```
$('.element_list').first().find('div').remove();
```

As a sidenote [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) only works from IE9 and up, using `querySelector` would add IE8 support as well

```
var all_el_ul = document.querySelector('.element_list');
```

Comment: @FelixKling - just noticed it in the comments, never used it before, and didn't even know it existed

Comment: @buzzsawddog: No, MDN is (mostly) valid for all browsers. And it explains why it works in the other browsers but not IE. Check the compatibility table.

Comment: @FelixKling Okay checked the table that you supplied and there is a BOLD RED text that said "Not Supported" under the column for IE...

Comment: Thank you ! I have to learn the difference between javascript and jquery. :)

Comment: @buzzsawddog: Yes. The question was *"Everything is working in FF, Chrome, Opera and others but not in IE. Could you please tell what is wrong?"* The answer: It's not supported in IE. adeneo's original answer was that `.remove()` does not exist at all, which was incorrect. It does exist, but not in IE.

Comment: @FelixKling - there's still a high probability that the OP confused jQuery with plain JS, as I don't think I've ever really seen the plain JS remove() method used in the wild.

Comment: @adeneo: True. Might be a lucky coincidence that it worked in the other browsers. Maybe you should still add paragraph about the jQuery confusion to your answer.

Comment: It's the same syntax, and the native method is supported in webkit and gecko? Who knows, but using the old parentNode.removeChild should work everywhere.

Comment: The MDN polyfill is the only solution that worked for me and is supported by IE 5 and up.

Answer (score 16):

Try adding this to the top of your JavaScript file:

```
if (!('remove' in Element.prototype)) {
  Element.prototype['remove'] = function () {
    if (this.parentNode) {
      this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    }
  };
}
```

It is a small `Element.remove()` polyfill.

Add that to your JS and `[element].remove()` should magically start working in IE.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When providing code, it i important to explain what your code does or how it solves OP's problem :)

Comment: It's a polyfill. Add that to the top of your JS file and it will now magically start working :)

Comment: I've added an explanation to the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: In which way (beyond syntax variation) does this code differ from solution #1 in AntoineSubit's answer which came in a year earlier ?

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I had to do for it to work in IE

```
if (typeof textField.remove === 'function') {
  textField.remove();
} else {
  textField.parentNode.removeChild(textField);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try this. (Support all browsers)

```
var child = document.getElementById(id);
child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
```