# Internet Explorer supported Version of .remove();

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-10

I have some code that  includes this:

```
item.parentElement.remove();
```

I tried running the script that contains this code in I.E. 10, and in the web console came up an error that said it did not support the

```
.remove;
```

method/property.

I'm not too worried about this because the target user won't be using Internet Explorer 7 out of 10 times, but it would be nice if it was compatible. Anyone know a version of

```
.remove();
```

that is supported by IE, Firefox, and chrome?  Thanks!

P.S. I'd love to include an image but it says I need ten rep.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428877/javascript-remove-doesnt-work-in-ie

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no version of that method for Internet Explorer :(

[Look here!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)